# What is the weak closure of $C_c(X)$ in $C_b(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, let $C_b(X)$ denote the bounded continuous functions with sup norm and $C_c(X)$ denote the continuous functions with compact support. I was wondering what the closure of $C_c(X)$ looks like in the weak topology i.e. topology induced by $C_b(X)^*$.

I am not sure if this is obvious, but I would appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Comment: @EricWofsey My apologies, that was a typo! I meant the dual of $C_b(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to Hahn-Banach, the closure of a subspace in the weak topology of a normed space is equal to the norm closure. Then it is easy to check (without using the Stone-Cech compactification as in Eric  Wofsey's answer) that $\overline{C_c(X)}=C_0(X)$ (the space of all continuous functions which, for all $\varepsilon>0$, are less than $\varepsilon$ outside some compact set). What you technically need is normality of locally compact Hausdorff spaces to find cut-off fuctions.

Comment: Ah I forgot about this! Mazur's theorem says the weak and strong closure of convex sets coincide. Thanks!

Comment: Any proof *with* $\beta X$ must surely beat a proof without it? $\beta X $ is nice!

Answer (score 3):

The weak closure of $C_c(X)$ is just $C_0(X)$.  Indeed, for any $x\in\beta X$, there is a functional on $C_b(X)\cong C(\beta X)$ given by evaluation at $x$.  When we identify $C_b(X)$ with $C(\beta X)$, $C_0(X)$ is just the set of functions which vanish on all of $\beta X\setminus X$, so it is weakly closed (it is the intersection of the kernels of the evaluation functionals for each $x\in \beta X\setminus X$).

Comment: Thanks very much!